# Convert a array with float numbers and string numbers to float

Tags: python

I have a string with float numbers where decimal separator is dot like 1.2, 4.2 and so on. And also other numbers where the decimal separator is comma like 2,5, 8,3 and so on. I would like to convert everything to float numbers with dot as decimal separator. I am trying with the following code

```
df["numbers"].apply(lambda x: x if x.is_float() else x.replace(',','.'))
```

When excecuting that line I receive a message that says: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_float'

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have no attribute `is_float`

If you want python to detect whether a string is a float, you can use `str.isdecimal()`.

*Note: You don't need that `if` statement. If the string doesn't contain a `','`, calling `str.replace(',','.')` will not trigger an error, it will just leave it as it is.*

Answer (score 0):

Convert `x` to `float` after replacing, so that it always is a float number instead of a string, try:

```
df["numbers"].apply(lambda x: x if x.is_float() else float(x.replace(',','.')))
```